# SciChart and SwiftyJSON

Tags: scichart

I am getting an [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error,

source 'https://github.com/ABTSoftware/PodSpecs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'HavingFunWithScichart' do

use_frameworks!

# Pods for HavingFunWithScichart

```
pod 'SciChart'

pod 'SwiftyJSON'

pod 'Alamofire'
```

end

I know that I am getting it due to the pre-install script file. For the script instructs only to install the SciChart pod file.

My question is, how can I add my SwiftyJSON and Alamofire so that I can do my 
pod install
??
Can anyone help me on how I can do this? I have checked and read over and over the documentation for Cocoapods but it does not cover anything on how I can over come the Pre-install script so that I can add the additional pods that I need for my project.

Answer (score 0):

How Do I delete this request please? I just heard back that it was a omission in their script and they will be fixing it.